# Firebase updating password (current pass and new pass)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've been struggling about the change password functionality of my app. I am confused on how I can compare the current pass and store the new password thru firebase database.
[image: This is my firebasedb structure][image: my xml form]

Please don't be harsh on me on comments, educate me please. I did research first before asking and tried several times. Most of the tutorials I found are about updating data while clicking an item in listview. The reason why I use db to store users is because I am going to create 2 keys that identifies if user is student or professor.I just want to ask help how am I able to implement change of password.

**ChangePassAccount.class**

```
 public class ChangePassAccount extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btnSave;
    EditText cpass, npass;
    String pass, newpass;

    DatabaseReference dbPDF;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_change_pass_account);

        dbPDF = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users").child("password");

        cpass = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.currentpass);
        npass = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.newpass);

        btnSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnsave);
        btnSave.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button);

        btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                pass = cpass.getText().toString();
                newpass = npass.getText().toString();


            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you storing user passwords in the database? That is a way to do it, but Firebase has Firebase-auth which is to be used as your authentication mechanism. Even better if you use Firebase-ui-auth then resetting password is already solved by the library. Firebase-ui is a ui binding library with the Firebase features and is supported officially by Google https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android

Answer (score 5):

i'll suggest you to using [firebase auth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/) to manage User Login or Changes password etc.. So maybe you only has to store user Data by [UserInfo](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/UserInfo)

this is a sample from [Firebase-Manage User](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users) to change the user password

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
String newPassword = "SOME-SECURE-PASSWORD";

user.updatePassword(newPassword)
        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "User password updated.");
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: it will make my work difficult sir, I used it that way so that I can add key to determine which type of user registers.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a very technical answer but I ran into this problem in iOS recently.

There is a FirebaseAuth method named 'reauthenticate' that can be found [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users). This takes a credential that you create by asking for the user's password and getting the email from currentUser. If this returns successful you will know that password is correct. After reauthenticated you can call updatePassword with the new password.

As a suggestion you should not need to store the password separately in the database since Firebase will handle all this for you.

Hope this helps out, good luck!

Comment: I'm not using auth sir, I just pass the values into the db and create child for pass.

Comment: Oh, sorry I made an assumption. In that case @Frank's answer is more fitting.

Answer (score 1):

You'd [use a Firebase Database transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions) for that. This gives you the current value, which you then compare against the old password. If they match, you return the new password.

Something like:

```
passwordRef.runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
    @Override
    public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
        String password = mutableData.getValue(String.class);
        if (password.equals(oldPassword) {
            mutableData.setValue(newPassword);
            return Transaction.success(mutableData);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, boolean b, DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Log.d(TAG, "passwordTransaction:onComplete:" + databaseError);
    }
});
```

Comment: Sir @Frank can you please share what is the passwordRef? also I'm using 2 edit text for that.

Comment: `passwordRef` is a `DatabaseReference` to the location in the database where you store the password. It could be that this is `dbPDF ` in your current code, but I'm not sure. My code assumes you've taken the old and new password from the two `TextView`s already and keep them in `oldPassword` and `newPassword` respectively.

Comment: Sir @Frank I want to override the oldpassword with the new password

Answer (score 0):

First you need to read the current password using single value event listener

```
pass = cpass.getText().toString();
newpass = npass.getText().toString();

dbPDF.addValueEventListener(addListenerForSingleValueEvent(){
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        // Get Post object and use the values to update the UI
        String password = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
        if(password.equals(pass)){
            dbPDF.setValue(newpass);
        }else{
            // show wrong pass dialog
        }
        // ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        // Getting Post failed, log a message
        Log.w(TAG, "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
        // ...
    }
};
```

Also make sure dbref is correct

```
String username = "helpmepls";
dbPDF = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users").child(username).child("password");
```